# Prevent an expression from evaluating a certain way (pattern-matching?)

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I've been trying to write some simple code to let me use physics vector notation: $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, $\hat{r}$, and $\hat{\theta}$.

```
Unprotect[Plus, Times, Dot];
Plus[Vector[xhat1_, yhat1_, rhat1_, ϕhat1_], 
   Vector[xhat2_, yhat2_, rhat2_, ϕhat2_]] := 
  Vector[xhat1 + xhat2, yhat1 + yhat2, 
   rhat1 + rhat2, ϕhat1 + ϕhat2];

Times[c_, Vector[xhat_, yhat_, rhat_, ϕhat_]] := 
  Vector[c xhat, c yhat, c rhat, c ϕhat];
Dot[Vector[xhat1_, yhat1_, rhat1_, ϕhat1_], 
   Vector[xhat2_, yhat2_, rhat2_, ϕhat2_]] := 
  xhat1 xhat2 + yhat1 yhat2 + rhat1 rhat2 + ϕhat1 ϕhat2;

Dot[scalar1_ vector1_Vector, 
   scalar2_ vector2_Vector] := (scalar1 vector1).(scalar2 vector2);
Protect[Plus, Times, Dot];
Format[Vector[xhat_, yhat_, rhat_, ϕhat_]] := 
  DisplayForm[
   xhat OverscriptBox["x", "^"] + yhat OverscriptBox["y", "^"] + 
    rhat OverscriptBox["r", "^"] + ϕhat OverscriptBox["ϕ", 
      "^"]];

Overhat[x] = Vector[1, 0, 0, 0];
Overhat[y] = Vector[0, 1, 0, 0];
Overhat[r] = Vector[0, 0, 1, 0];
Overhat[θ] = Vector[0, 0, 0, 1];
```

I've been having trouble getting my dot product operation to work correctly. The source of the problem is that `Dot` has a higher precedence than `Times` so expressions such as 
`Overhat[x].y Overhat[y]` (that is $\hat{x}.y \hat{y}$) evaluates as `Times[Dot[Overhat[x],y],Overhat[y]]`. I don't want to evaluate `Dot[Overhat[x],y]` because that would be a vector dotted with a scalar. How can I prevent *Mathematica* from evaluating it in this way. If I could simply tell it to give precedence to Times over Dot then it would work, but this is probably impossible. Perhaps there is some clever pattern matching stuff I can to set how the expression evaluates before *Mathematica* can do anything with it. Such as

`Times[Dot[v1_Vector, scalar_], v2_Vector] := scalar Dot[v1, v2];`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work though.

This is the second post, the first one being 
[How can I use a unit vector notation found in physic texts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211502/how-can-i-use-a-unit-vector-notation-found-in-physic-texts), though it is somewhat unrelated.

**Edit: **
Mr. Wizard's solution is pretty much what I am looking for. But I found some unusual behavior that I couldn't find the explanation for. If we set $Pre twice, the second time seems to unset it:

```
(*First set*)
$Pre = Function[, Unevaluated[#] /. a_.b_ c_ :> a.(b c), HoldAll];
Overhat[x] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; Overhat[y] = {a, b, c, d, e};
Overhat[x].y Overhat[y]
```

```
(*Evaluates as expected*)
a y + 2 b y + 3 c y + 4 d y + 5 e y
```

```
(*Second set*)
$Pre = Function[, Unevaluated[#] /. a_.b_ c_ :> a.(b c), HoldAll];
Overhat[x] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; Overhat[y] = {a, b, c, d, e};
Overhat[x].y Overhat[y]
```

```
(*Evaluates as if $Pre had never been set*)
{a {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y, b {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y, c {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y, 
 d {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y, e {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y}
```

Even stranger is that `$Pre` doesn't appear to change between sets (now going into a new notebook):

```
$Pre
```

Outputs: `$Pre`
Now if we set it:

```
$Pre = Function[, Unevaluated[#] /. a_.b_ c_ :> a.(b c), HoldAll];
```

Then: `$Pre`

Outputs: `Function[Null, Unevaluated[#1] /. (a_).(b_) c_ :> a.(b c), HoldAll]`

And doing the setting process again:

```
$Pre = Function[, Unevaluated[#] /. a_.b_ c_ :> a.(b c), HoldAll];
```

Then: `$Pre`

Outputs: `Function[Null, Unevaluated[#1] /. (a_).(b_) c_ :> a.(b c), HoldAll]`

So it appears to be set, but $Pre doesn't apply to this expression as (at least as I) would expect:

```
Overhat[x] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; Overhat[y] = {a, b, c, d, e};
Overhat[x].y Overhat[y]
```

Outputs:

```
a {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y, b {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y, c {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y, d {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y, e {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.y}
```

Is there some hidden feature of $Pre interacting with itself that makes it difficult to get these successive evaluations to work as expected?

**Edit 2: **
Following the advice of Mr. Wizard, here is the solution:

```
If[ValueQ[$Pre], , $Pre = 
   Function[, Unevaluated[#] /. a_. b_ . c_ d_ :> (a b).(c d), 
    HoldAll]];
```

Insert this anywhere in the above code to resolve the dot product problem.

Comment: you can always use `()` to control precedence. Can you not write `Overhat[x].(y Overhat[y])` for example?

Comment: @Nasser Ya your right. I could just use parentheses explicitly and maybe its a good idea to do that instead. But in typical usage that sort of thing isn't necessary because we understand immediately the expression ```y Overhat[y]``` to be a vector; unlike _Mathematica_ and (my implementation of) ```Vector```. Also (and this is a little lazy) I wanna avoid having to use parentheses with almost all applications of ```Dot```.

Comment: Messing with the definitions of basic functions such as `Plus`, `Times` and `Dot` is always a bad idea.

Comment: @m_goldberg In this example I could change to ```CenterDot```, ```CircleTimes```, and ```CirclePlus``` and it would solve that problem, and I probably will in the long run. But I am restricted in what I can use as operators by the preferences, and I think the same problem will remain because I am still stuck using ```Times``` for multiplication by a scalar (unless I use something wacky as the dot product operator). I'm trying to avoid using something heavy duty like the ```Notation``` package. Theres got to be some way to tell MMA how to evaluate an expression of the listed form.

Comment: Related: [(19067)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19067/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this only has to work for manual input consider [`$Pre`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre.html):

```
$Pre = Function[, Unevaluated[#] /. a_ . b_ c_ :> a.(b c), HoldAll];

Overhat[x] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; Overhat[y] = {a, b, c, d, e};

Overhat[x].y Overhat[y]
```

> ```
> a y + 2 b y + 3 c y + 4 d y + 5 e y
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard this was the solution I was looking for. But I ran into some strange behavior that I described more in an edit to the original question (it took a lot of space) that I'm sure you know the explanation for.

Comment: @Tanner Two points.  (1) `a_.b_ c_` is NOT the same as `a_ . b_ c_` because `a_.` parses as `Optional[Pattern[a, _]]`.  Perhaps I should have written `Dot[a_, b_] c_` for robustness. (2) The second definition of `$Pre` is itself modified by the existing Function; here is a stand-alone example:  `Function[, Unevaluated[#] /. Dot[a_, b_] c_ :> a.(b c), HoldAll] /. 
 Dot[a_, b_] c_ :> a.(b c)` — within the result the left hand side of `RuleDelayed` is transformed into `(a_).(b_ c_)` which is the new precedence rather than the original one.