# Indicate Unit Vectors in Solve

Tags: equation-solving, vector

I'm solving a system defined by two rays. The rays originate from two points `{x,y,z}` and `{x,y,z-h}`. They go in directions (unit vectors) `{u1,v1,w1}` and `{u2,v2,w2}`. The rays are connected by a line segment of length `l`. The endpoints of the line segment are `t` units down the length of each ray. The variable to solve for is `t`.

[image]

This solution is all well and good, but I notice in the output I have collections of terms like `u1^2 ... + v1^2 ... + w1^2`. I know that `{u1,v1,w1}` and `{u2,v2,w2}` are unit vectors, so these could be substituted with a 1, and maybe even other simplifications could occur. I modified the solve like so:

[image]

This looks like a step in the right direction. (I tried `Norm[{u1,v1,w1}]==1` but it had no effect.) So, I tried constraining `{u2,v2,w2}` to a unit vector.

[image]

Sadly, it blows up to a size even larger than the first output. Doing this last step manually could be "an exercise left up to me," but I'm curious if there's some way I could approach this that yields better results. I thought maybe there was some way to declare a vector as a unit vector, and came across [How can I use a unit vector notation found in physic texts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211502/how-can-i-use-a-unit-vector-notation-found-in-physic-texts) but I wasn't able to glean anything useful from it. How can I let Mathematica know that a vector is a unit vector so that it can use it as a hint in simplifying output?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: `Solve` by itself does not do everything it can to `Simplify` a result. That makes `Solve` faster and you can use `Simplify` only if need be. This `FullSimplify[(-h(2w1-2w2)-Sqrt[h^2(2w1-2w2)^2-4(h^2-l^2)(u1^2-2u1*u2+u2^2+v1^2-2v1*v2+v2^2+w1^2-2w1*w2+w2^2)])/(2(u1^2-2u1*u2+u2^2+v1^2-2v1*v2+v2^2+w1^2-2w1*w2+w2^2)), Norm[{u1,v1,w1}]==1&& Norm[{u2,v2,w2}]==1]` gives a substantially smaller result, but only because I have included the second argument to `FullSimplify` telling it about two of your assumptions, otherwise Mathematica would never know. With more assumptions an even smaller result?

Comment: Try doing this `Replace[Solve[{EuclideanDistance[r1, r2] == l}, 
   t], {u1^2 -> 1 - v1^2 - w1^2, u2^2 -> 1 - v2^2 - w2^2}, {6, 
   10}] // Simplify` . The idea is that you replace the solution at different "levels" inside the equation. To understand this more check out the help for `Replace[]`